# How to get CPU consumed by each Apex

Tags: apex, exception, cpulimit, limitexception, cpu-time

I am trying to find some way to build an application/report which shows CPU time consumed by each class per execute.

Please refer below table to get more details of the ask.

| APEX Class | Consumed CPU Time |
| --- | --- |
| First class | 1000ms |
| Second class | 1564654ms |

If any one has built such an application/report then do let me know, Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

CPU time isn't measured by class that way, so it's impossible to build such an app directly. You'd have to add a method somewhere that every other method would have to call to log the time used. You can get a log of how long every action took, though, if you have the [Event Monitoring](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_intro) feature available, but note that it comes at some cost (i.e. talk to your Sales Associate about it). Aside from that, it's usually more beneficial to talk about how much time a class took per use, rather than per day, to which I'd say you may want to write unit tests that display elapsed CPU time somehow (in the log files, or maybe assertions, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @sfdcfox, what I want to see is how much time a class took per use/ per execute. do you aware of any method (object name) from event monitoring from which I can get this details ?